# VHDL for scientific computing

Tags: vhdl, fpga, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

I was wondering if folks use VHDL/FPGAs in scientific computing.

An example scenario that I was thinking off was say:

1. Construct an arbitrary precision floating point adder
2. Configure an FPGA board to then add such numbers

So I was looking for references (example code) where VHDL/FPGAs have been used in scientific computing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question might better be directed towards Google.  Here is a report on a project to build an FPGA-based supercomputer: http://www.fhpca.org/download/RSSI07-Maxwell.pdf which might get you started on your researches.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @HighPerformanceMark, I think someone passed that reference to me on another question a couple of days ago. I was looking for more vocational level material that illustrates specific solutions used for Scientific Computing.

Comment: FPGAs used to drive the largest astrophysics simulations in the past but is now being outplaced by GPGPU computing.

Comment: @HristoIliev, Do you have a reference or an explanation on why that happened. I was actually thinking the flow of things would be the other way.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://www.ari.uni-heidelberg.de/mitarbeiter/spurzem/isc09paper.pdf) quite informative. It is somewhat old, but the leading author recently gave a talk here and showed the audience quite similar (if not the same) figures, so things haven't changed much since the time the article was published. I would say that migration to GPUs is driven mainly by the better price/performance ratio and next by the easier programming model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several vendors who build heterogeneous computing systems using FPGAs. I doubt you'll find complete source code for such systems.

[SRC Computing](http://www.srccomp.com/products/highdensitymapstation.asp)

[Convey Computer](http://www.conveycomputer.com/solutions/research/)

[Mitrionics](http://www.mitrionics.com/?page=the_company). A reseller of other systems.

[Novo-G](http://www.chrec.org/ngforum/). An academic project.

Answer (score 1):

Look into radio astronomy.  With arrays such as the VLA and ALMA, the massively parallel correlator is the part that could be considered most important.  These typically use FPGAs but could use custom-designed chips for extreme performance at higher cost.

Some fine reading:
https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/cdl/digital-signal-processing
http://web.njit.edu/~gary/728/Lecture8.html